# Imported OBJ Model doesn't render

Tags: import

i imported an .OBJ (C4D native) model of a car from turbosquid. Everything worked fine, changed some colours of textures, wanted click render - nothing happens. Either in rendered view, and also in the normal rendering. I have the suspicion, that the model is to complex? It says 333.805 Verts and 320.000 Faces. I can't really put that into perspective. On the other hand, my computer is quiet beefy at an i7 Quadcore at 3,4Ghz and 32GB of RAM.

Is there anything I can do from here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your issue could have multiple causes.
Does the render start or is it only your model which doesn't turn up in the render output?
My first guess would be that you have your object switched off in the render view (camera icon located in the outliner)

Comment: Render does not start. Timer's stuck at 00:00:00. Also none of the objects are turned off for rendering.

Comment: It's really difficult to guess what could be the cause. 
It would help if you could upload the file but because of the licenses of turbosquid I do not recommend it.
Firstly: your model is not to complex, it should work just fine.
However, do you have any modifiers applied to it?
Did you import the .OBJ in a clean new file?
What version of blender are you using?
I'd say check your render settings, render layers, material setup, texture sizes, animation, possible particle systems.

Comment: hey, first - thank you so much for taking the time.
i imported the OBJ into a clean file, yes. None of the Layers have any modifiers applied to them. My blender version is 2.78. There is no animation, particle systems or obscure texture sizes.

Comment: Have you ruled out everything else besides that the imported object is the issue?
Try deleting everthing, add a cube, assing a new basic material to the cube, save this as a copy, reload the blendfile and try rendering the cube.
If the problem persist. Then you can upload the blendfile with the cube only for testing by the community.

Comment: Done, problem persists. Uploaded the file here: https://we.tl/t-EqQbD4LwmQ

Comment: v2.76b: render and preview OK.

Comment: Updated to 2.79b - Works just fine. Thanks for the help anyways!